# Best way to find out if an (upcast) instance doesn't implement a particular interface

Tags: c#, .net, interface

Maybe the need to do this is a 'design smell' but thinking about another question, I was wondering what the cleanest way to implement the **inverse** of this:

```
foreach(ISomethingable somethingableClass in collectionOfRelatedObjects)
{
  somethingableClass.DoSomething();
}
```

i.e. How to get/iterate through all the objects that *don't* implement a particular interface?

Presumably you'd need to start by upcasting to the highest level:

```
foreach(ParentType parentType in collectionOfRelatedObjects)
{
  // TODO: iterate through everything which *doesn't* implement ISomethingable 
}
```

Answer by solving the TODO: in the cleanest/simplest and/or most efficient way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
collectionOfRelatedObjects.Where(o => !(o is ISomethingable))
```

Answer (score 6):

Something like this?

```
foreach (ParentType parentType in collectionOfRelatedObjects) {
    if (!(parentType is ISomethingable)) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably best to go all the way and improve the variable names:

```
foreach (object obj in collectionOfRelatedObjects)
{
    if (obj is ISomethingable) continue;

    //do something to/with the not-ISomethingable
}
```

Answer (score 0):

J D OConal's is the best way to do this but as a side note, you can use the as keyword to cast an object, and it'll return null if its not of that type.

So something like:

```
foreach (ParentType parentType in collectionOfRelatedObjects) {
    var obj = (parentType as ISomethingable);
    if (obj == null)  {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With some help from the LINQ extension method OfType<>(), you can write:

```
using System.Linq;

...

foreach(ISomethingable s in collection.OfType<ISomethingable>())
{
  s.DoSomething();
}
```